# The wrong group to be "in" Or "on"?

Tags: prepositions, collocation

> 'They either participate with some decorum, or recognise this is the
>   wrong group to be on!'

Is that sentence idiomatically and grammatically correct? Can *on* and *in* be used in this sentence?

Comment: *In* would be fine; *on* doesn't make sense.

Comment: In may work, On does not!

Comment: @user61979: yes, 'in' is better with group but informally, it sounds OK to me to be 'on' a group (like you're 'on' a committee).

Comment: I have never heard of being 'on a group'.

Answer (score 1):

Since your are  a bit formal in your style.  I'd say: 
.. or they recognise that this is the wrong group **to be part of**.

Answer (score 1):

The sudden ending on a preposition isn't incorrect, but it clangs a bit in the context of your formal style. I would suggest avoiding the issue and rephrasing as:

"They either participate with some decorum, or recognise this is not the group for them".

Comment: I don't see how ending the sentence with a preposition has any bearing on the formality of the style. Would you also consider "They either participate with some decorum, or recognise this is the wrong group to belong to" as being undignified in some way, simply because it ends with _to?_ In other words, what is the basis for your assumption that when a preposition terminates a sentence, the formality of the register is decreased?

Comment: @Erik -- A major source of the formality of the style of that sentence comes from somewhat archaic and pedantic word choice. That would be complemented by the application of a somewhat archaic approach to grammar. If you want something to sound like it was written by an angry school teacher then it makes sense to use their rules, however fictitious, to avoid anachronism.

Comment: (I don't mean any of the above to be a criticism of the choice of style, which could easily be appropriate).

Answer (score 0):

The preposition 'on' is used to show that something is sitting on the surface of something else, like you would sit on a stool or a book would sit on a shelf.  'In', however, would be the better word to use as you are included as a member of the group, not sitting on top of them.

Comment: This is just not helpful. As others have pointed out, it is idiomatic to be _on_ a committee: the primary meaning of prepositions is of almost no help in determining their idiomatic use in transferred senses.